# how to force my app NOT to use the 3g data proxy setting

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and on devices pre 4.0 (ics) the app works fine connecting to http and https backends on WiFi and 3G data connections. But on my ICS 4.0.3 device, the app ONLY connects to https via WiFi (it connects fine to http on both wifi and 3g). I realised that by manually going to the APN settings and removing the proxy, my app can connect to the https backend via 3g. So my question is how can i force **httpclient** to **NOT** use the proxy settings via code? Thanks

Comment: well since i can't self answer.. here's how i solved my problem


    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(ConnRouteParams.NO_HOST);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);


Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: This works for me but I don't understand much about it -- is there any downside to not using the proxy?  What is the purpose of the proxy?

Comment: I imagine this would only work where a proxy is being using for some internal network or something. For carriers where a proxy is required for data then this may not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thanks *Cool Dude* for answering your question yourself. I had the same problem but was not using HttpClient but instead HttpURLConnection directly. 
In that case the solution is the following:

```
myUrl.openConnection(java.net.Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

Comment: Do you set NO_PROXY for all platforms or just for 4.0.3/4.0.4 ?

Comment: Only for SSL connections, but for all platforms. Works like a charm.