# HTTPS exception in 3G with some Android devices

Tags: java, android, sockets, https, socketexception

Here's my problem:

I want to make a HTTPS request on my server using a self-signed certificate. Works fine in WLAN with Galaxy S2 (v4.0.3), Nexus S (4.0.4), Xperia Ray (4.0.3) and Galaxy Ace (2.3.6).

When testing in 3G, it works only on Galaxy Ace and Xperia Ray. On the others I got a `Socket is closed: java.net.SocketException`.

On [this page](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29509), I found a solution. I had a request property `Connection : close`. But without this header, I get a different error: `Handshake timeout`.

What could be so different in these devices to obtain these different results?

For https requests, I use the `javax.net.ssl` package. I use a client private key for the request.

**EDIT**: I tested with others SIM card, that's weird: with one, it works on Nexus S but not on Galaxy S. With a second, works fine on everyone. My conclusion is: some operators may bridle particular requests or data transfert. I don't know why, I'll contact them to more informations

**EDIT2:** 
Solution here:
[how to force my app NOT to use the 3g data proxy setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905521/how-to-force-my-app-not-to-use-the-3g-data-proxy-setting)

Comment: I face a similar issue. I tested on two phones (2.3.6 and 4.0.x) with the same simcard. The ICS gives this socket connect problem.

Answer (score 3):

This problem, as per your edit, is indeed caused by operator proxy settings.

Your link resolved my issue, but it took a little figuring out how to use *ProxySelector* and *Proxy.NO_PROXY*, so I thought I'd post my solution here for completeness.

Note that I am overriding all URI attempts from the app, which is handy if you have connections through something like the Facebook SDK that you don't want to hack yourself.

```
ProxySelector proxySelector = new ProxySelector() {

        @Override
        public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
            List<Proxy> proxies = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
            proxies.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
            return proxies;
        }

        @Override
        public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress address,
                IOException failure) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);
```